# NodeJS Setting a timeout for nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js

Made a small scrip that grabs a list of emails from another file. Then using the forEach to use the mail function from nodemailer to send an email to each of them. My problem is I want to have a timeout between each email sent. I have tried a couple of things and I am just purely stuck. If anyone could give me a hand. This is my first project trying to code lol.

```
        'use strict';
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var fs = require('fs');
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Load Victims
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
var victims = fs.readFileSync('./victims.txt', 'utf8').split("\r\n");
var letter = fs.readFileSync('./letter.txt', 'utf8');

victims.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        pool: true,
        maxConnections: 1,
        maxMessages: 1,
        rateDelta: 3000,
        rateLimit: 1,
        host: 'mail.asrebaziemast.com',
        port: 587,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        tls: {
        // do not fail on invalid certs
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
        auth: {
            user: "a1@asrebaziemast.com", // generated ethereal user
            pass: "D@gician#d21" // generated ethereal password
        }
    });
        let mailOptions = {
        from: '"Freddy Mang" <a1@asrebaziemast.com>', // sender address
        to: item, // list of receivers
        subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
        html: letter, // html body
        encoding: 'base64'
    };
    setTimeout(function () {
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId, item);
    });
    }, 5000); 

});
```

Comment: Tried using the rateLimit and rateDelta aswell as you can see to make it try to send only 1 message per couple seconds but still couldn't get that to work. I believe it has something to do with I need to add "promises" but just not too familiar with it. What would really be cool if someone could guide me in the way and tell me what I should research and learn to properly handle this situation. I appreciate it.

Comment: So just to understand you correctly - you want to queue emails to send out 5s after the previous? Any particular reason why you are doing this?

Comment: I wanted a timeout due to a lot of SMTP providers don't like mass emails and give you a certain amount of email per hour limits etc.

Comment: victims? seriously? are you spamming? lol

Comment: wow, victims, I can't appreciate it, but wow

Comment: Did my answer help solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `rateLimit` / `rateDelta` options are what you want here, the problem is you are creating a new transporter instance *per email*.

Move the transport creation outside the `forEach` to reuse the same instance e.g.

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  pool: true,
  maxConnections: 1,
  maxMessages: 1,
  rateDelta: 3000,
  rateLimit: 1,
  host: 'mail.asrebaziemast.com',
  port: 587,
  secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
  tls: {
    // do not fail on invalid certs
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  },
  auth: {
    user: "a1@asrebaziemast.com", // generated ethereal user
    pass: "D@gician#d21" // generated ethereal password
  }
});
victims.forEach(item => {
  transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"Freddy Mang" <a1@asrebaziemast.com>', // sender address
    to: item, // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
    html: letter, // html body
    encoding: 'base64'
  }, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId, item);
  });
});
```

Comment: Tried that. It's not console.logging the Message sent for I can see if it is stopping or not anymore. I appreciate your help so much.

Comment: @NoxBin so then I'd start to question the whether the configuration and/or the data is accurate. Can you show a snippet of what `victims.txt` looks like?

Comment: Oh no it's sending the email. it's just not console logging.

Comment: @NoxBin I did have a typo in the callback which I've corrected, that _may_ have been the problem.